# Get text without mark up from kendo editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, rich-text-editor, kendo-editor

I am using kendo editor in my application to capture some information. One of the requirements is to save the text entered in the same without any markup. I understand that the piece of code:

```
$("#editor").data("kendoEditor").value();
```

will give me the text entered in the control with the markup. But is there any way to retrieve only the text entered? I even wanted the number of lines in the text area that the content occupies.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
var text = $("<div/>").html($("#editor").data("kendoEditor").value()).text();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code :

```
try {
    var value = $("#editor").data("kendoEditor").value();
    var text = value.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"");
    alert(text);
}
catch (e) { }
```